# Is there a key bind for Visual Studio code to annotate a type in typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, type-annotation

For example, let's say I have the following code

```
const foo = "this is foo";
```

I would like to click on foo and press a key to annotate a type

```
const foo: string = "this is foo";
```

Visual studio code already knows the type, because is there when you hover over it. How would I make a key bind?

Answer (score 2):

You can auto-add types by hovering over the variable and clicking `Quick fix → infer parameter types from usage`. The keyboard shortcut for this is `⌘ + .`, then `↵`.

VSCode already displaying the correct type out of the box means that typescript is inferring it for you. Adding the same declaration again would just add to the word count.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i get "No code action available", but i can see the type on hover.
There is no quickfix available to add/change the type either.

Comment: Weird, this VSCode feature works without special configuration for me. Can't reproduce this unfortunately.

Comment: same thing. Right clicking also doesn't bring anything

Answer (score 1):

Add `"typescript.inlayHints.variableTypes.enabled": true,` to your `settings.json` to see the [automatic type hints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-editing#_inlay-hints).

Note that this doesn't *insert* the type annotations into your code, but it does allow you to see them as you work.